# Why is my MongDB not able to access the data?

Tags: mongodb

I've got a MongoDB instance running on ECR/Kubernetes. As far as I can tell, the db path is the default path:

```
root@mongodb-ddn44:/data/db# ps -aux | grep -i mongod
mongodb      1  0.1  0.2 1112480 78564 ?       Ssl  13:51   0:13 mongod --bind_ip_all
root       171  0.0  0.0  11284   976 pts/1    S+   16:03   0:00 grep --color=auto -i mongod
```

In addition, when I check the `/data/db/` directory it seems to have content:

```
root@mongodb-ddn44:/data/db# du -sh /data/db/
1.5G    /data/db/
```

However, I don't see any databases with any content:

```
root@mongodb-ddn44:/data/db# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("65eb0346-bac0-4a80-ae49-88b8c0adf223") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.10
Server has startup warnings:
2021-07-16T13:51:22.594+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2021-07-16T13:51:22.594+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2021-07-16T13:51:22.594+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2021-07-16T13:51:22.595+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
---
Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---

> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

And, at this point, I'm stuck.